# Jquery hover() not triggering on hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-hover

I have an weird problem. I'm trying to use jquery hover. But i can't get it to work correctly. The only way i can get i to work is by clicking on it. Are there any who can see there the issue might be?
The HTML Part:

```
<a class="preview"><img id="EquipmentInfoPanelElementUrl" height="100" width="100" src="temp.png" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a>
```

The javascript part:

```
  $("a.preview").hover(function (e) {
            $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + $("#EquipmentInfoPanelElementUrl").attr("src") + "' alt='Image preview' /></p>");
            $("#preview").css("top", (e.pageY - 10) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + 30) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
        },
     function () {
         $("#preview").remove();
     });

        $("a.preview").mousemove(function (e) {
            $("#preview").css("top", (e.pageY - 10) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + 30) + "px");
        });
```

Comment: Is your JavaScript executed at the bottom of the page and/or in a document.ready event handler?

Comment: also is preview created by javascript as well?

Comment: It's in document Ready.

Comment: Seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/pgq7ncx7/

Comment: I don't think your mousemove is necessary... should be able to do it with just hover and be fine. I don't see your mousemove actually doing anything important, unless I'm wrong... >.>

Answer (score 1):

It's working. (Latest jQuery library)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>jQuery Autocomplete</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

      $("a.preview").hover(function(e) {
          $("body").append("<p id='preview'><img src='" + $("#EquipmentInfoPanelElementUrl").attr("src") + "' alt='Image preview' /></p>");
          $("#preview").css("top", (e.pageY - 10) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + 30) + "px").fadeIn("fast");
        },
        function() {
          $("#preview").remove();
        });

      $("a.preview").mousemove(function(e) {
        $("#preview").css("top", (e.pageY - 10) + "px").css("left", (e.pageX + 30) + "px");
      });

    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a class="preview"><img id="EquipmentInfoPanelElementUrl" height="100" width="100" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="gallery thumbnail" /></a>
</body>

</html>
```